# Regex Matching - Content within brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a fast question, I just don't know many Regex tricks and can't find documentation  for this exact point:

Lets say I have the string:

```
'I know [foo] and [bar] about Regex'
```

I want to do a JS Regex pattern that makes an array of each bracket encapsulation. Result:

```
['[foo]', '[bar]']
```

I currently have:

```
str.match(/\[(.*)\]/g);
```

But this returns:

```
'[foo] and [bar]'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
```

Use a `?` modifier to make the `*` quantifier non-greedy. A non-greedy quantifier will match the *shortest* string possible rather than the longest, which is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
var str = 'I know [foo] and [bar] about Regex';
str.match(/\[([^\[\]]*)\]/g);
```

Your regex is partially wrong because of `(.*)`, which makes your pattern to allow **any** character between `[` and `]`, which includes `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var array = 'I know [foo] and [bar] about Regex'.match(/(\[[^\]]+\])/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
\\[[^\\]]+\\]
```

Your regex is partially wrong because of `(.*)`, which makes your pattern to allow any character between `[` and `]`, which includes `[` and `]`.

Comment: This looks a whole lot like [Arun P Johny](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17100719/2521769)'s answer from a year ago.