# Extract contents within brackets using R and Regex

Tags: regex, r

I have a data-frame that contains user names in the format

```
"John Smith (Company Department)"
```

I want to extract the department from the username to add it to its own separate column.

I have tried the below code but it fails if the user name is something like

```
"John Smith (Company Department) John Doe)"
```

Can anyone help. `Reg-ex` isn't my strong suit and the below code will only work if the username is non standard like my example above with multiple brackets

```
strcol <- "John Smith (FPO Sales) John Doe)"

start_loc <- str_locate_all(pattern ='\\(FPO ',strcol)[[1]][2]
end_loc <- str_locate_all(pattern ='\\)',strcol)[[1]][2]
substr(strcol,start_loc +1, end_loc -1)))
```

Expected Output:

```
Sales
```

[I have also tried the post here using non greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100708/regex-matching-content-within-brackets),  but got the following error:

> **Error: '[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/["**

Note: the company will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sub`

```
> strcol <- "John Smith (FPO Sales) John Doe)"
> sub(".*\\(FPO[^)]*?(\\w+)\\).*", "\\1", strcol)
[1] "Sales"
```

- `.*\\(FPO` would match all the characters upto the `(FPO`
- `[^)]*?` this would match any char but not of `)` zero or ore times.
- `(\\w+)\\)` captures one or more word characters exists at the last within the same brackets itself.
- `.*` would match all the remaining characters.
- So by replacing all the matched chars with the chars present inside group index 1 will give you the desired output.

OR

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(strcol, perl("FPO[^)]*?\\K\\w+(?=\\))"))
[1] "Sales"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain the regex for the sub example please if its not too much trouble?

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub('.*\\s(.*)\\).*\\)$','\\1',strcol)
[1] "Sales"
```